# Website usage tracking

Tags: asp.net, .net, analytics, tracking, web-analytics

What are available options of intranet-hosted (e.g. not Google Analytics) usage tracking tools for web application? This application is written in ASP.NET and used in intranet. So ideally if hosted part would be on .NET for consistency. I want to see where user clicks, what pages visit, what buttons clicks.

Comment: Piwik might be of interest to you - though it still requires internal hosting.

Comment: @Hippo - thanks for hosting comment, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can only recommend [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), which i used for some time, and produced great results (and it is open-source!)

Comment: Thanks but ideally would be .NET tool, this is PHP.

Comment: sorry, didn't see you asked for .net tool.

Comment: Surprisingly no one can recommend nothing in .NET. So I am accepting your answer, thanks.

Comment: For anyone still finding this answer, there is now a .Net client for Piwik.  Also, I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing it wouldn't have been ultra difficult to write C# wrappers around the Http client.

http://piwik.org/blog/2013/02/c-sharp-tracking-and-analytics-api/

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you wouldn't use SaaS version for usage tracking?

Commercial solutions such as Totango (my company) honor your privacy and confidentiality.

Comment: It's not my decision (corporate).